# Finding a way to accomplish memcpy without using memcpy

Tags: c++, linux

I would like the accomplish the same result that happens with memcpy without actually using memcpy.

Here is the code I would like to change away from memcpy.

```
memcpy((char *) &(serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr), 
    (char *)(server->h_addr), server->h_length);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: memcpy is causing an error, and to fix I would have to reinstall the OS.

Comment: And the answer is, of course, "yes". `memcpy` is a rather trivial function to reimplement yourself.

Comment: I don't believe you. I think you're misinterpreting what's going on.

Comment: @user1601045 Are you sure about that? If `memcpy` didn't work none of your programs would work..

Comment: I am building on an ubuntu 12.04 machine, and running on a red hat os and the clib file on the server is an older version than what I am using to build on my local machine

Comment: Not wanting to be rude, but are you sure `memcpy` is broken? For such a trivial function to be broken is extremely unlikely...

Comment: It's not memcpy that's broken, but the arguments you are passing to it are wrong. Without some extra context about your program, we can't help you.

Comment: Well I get an error message, if I have the memcpy line in my code, if I comment it out, my program runs fine

Comment: I will assume you first performed a google search on "memcpy source" (since failing to do that would imply you do not value even your own time, much less anyone else's)... so what was it about what you found there that you needed help with?

Comment: Well, in that case, you either need to statically link your program, or compile it on the Red Hat machine. Even if you get memcpy to work, something else *will* break further down the line, since all library versions *must* be identical for everything else you use.

Comment: I would think that to be true, but I have seven c++ apps that I've built on my ubuntu machine and run on the red hat server without this issue. Only now when I implement the memcpy function does it throw the error

Comment: When you say you get an error... do you mean a compile-time error. Maybe you just forgot to `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: A runtime error it compiles without issues

Comment: What's the error message you get with memcpy?

Comment: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found. I know why that doesn't work, but I would just like to not use memcpy

Comment: I see no reason to write it yourself (besides learning how it works of course), code context would be very helpful into why you are getting the error in the first place.

Comment: Assuming your dyna-load is failing (and I suspect that greatly), is there any reason whatsoever a person coding in C with the kind of code exhibited in that single line demonstrated cannot fathom the concept of a for-loop with a pair of unsigned char* ptrs ? or am i the only one slamming his head on a table right now?

Comment: is there any reason whatsoever a person coding in C with the kind of code exhibited in that single line demonstrated cannot fathom the concept of a for-loop with a pair of unsigned char* ptrs?

lol, yeah, I don't have a good grasp of pointers. I have only been programming in cpp for three weeks

Comment: You've made a mistake in your code and are writing to a random location in memory. This is causing your problem. See my answer below.

Comment: I would suggest that before you open a socket with that addr and proceed to start invoking send() and recv() that you dust off the class text and learn about pointers, or trust me; you're be in a world of hurt in short order. Its not complicated, but it also isn't optional to be effective in C/C++. Gotta learn sometime; better now than a few thousand core dumps from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recode `memcpy` easily with a for loop. If the compiler provides intrinsics, you can use them. Gcc has `__builtin_memcpy`. But the most important thing is that you are probably wrong in doing so, `memcpy` is used everywhere and can’t be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: you found this code somewhere on the web, and have accidentally reversed the parameters to the `memcpy()` call:

```
memcpy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, 
    server->h_length);
```

Just switch them back, your runtime error will disappear.